# How can I use single and normal quotation marks in the same string?

Tags: lua

I am working on a project, in which you type your input sentence, and I need to be able to use " and ' in the sentence, such as Input = "I said, "Hi what's up?" print(Input) in which I get an error. If anyone knows how to fix this that would be great.

Comment: In Lua forgot to mention it

Answer (score 2):

See https://www.lua.org/pil/2.4.html. Lua has very interesting feature to declare string with square brackets:

```lua
input = [[I said, "Hi what's up?"]]
input = "I said, \"Hi what's up?\""
input = 'I said, "Hi what\'s up?"'
```

Answer (score 0):

I will tell some things in addition to what @Darius told above

When you tried to add a quatation mark inside a string, the lua interpreter get confused and break your string after the next quation mark without reaching the end of the line. That's the reason for the error.

Try to understand it by the following code

```lua
str = "Hello I"m somebody" -- here the interpreter will think str equals to "Hello I" at first, and then it will find some random characters after which may make it confused (as m somebody is neither a variable nor a keyword)"

-- you can also see the way it got confused by looking at the highlighted code

--What you can do to avoid this is escaping the quotes
str = "Hello I\"m somebody" -- here the interpreter will treat \" as a raw character (") and parse the rest.
```

You can also use the escape character () with others such as `\'`, `\"`, `\[`, `\n` (newline character), `\t` (tab) and so on.